# Giving users an editable homepage/business directory

Tags: users, user-roles

I'm currently working on a site which requires a business directory for 80 tennants.

In an ideal world I'd like the administrator to create a user for each business and a page in a custom post type. The user would then be restricted to editing and updating only that page.

On the front end these posts would be listed on a page which is searchable.

Has anyone encountered such requirements in the past, any tips, ideas. All feedback welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen Role Manager used to restrict editor access only to pages on which they have been designated as authors. Would guess it would work with custom post types.